# Using a non-supported Authentication Provider with Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Has anyone gone about integrating authentication with a provider that is not currently provided by Firebase. Was interested in implementing an authentication strategy for Meetup.com.

Comment: Firebase provides a [library for generating tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html#section-custom) from pre-existing credentials. This is the standard way for using external auth tools.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Auth0.com to integrate with most OAuth2 providers (including meetup.com)

Overview docs here: https://auth0.com/docs/overview

Auth0 Firebase Docs: https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/firebase

Comment: integrate with any / integrate with most

Comment: Thanks @Kato, I've changed my answer to use safer language ("most" instead of "any") :)